# The paradigm of annotations

Tags: symfony, annotations

I'm new to Symfony and I was really surprised when I saw that very important parts of program logic are "hidden" in the annotations. Or actually in PHP comments. I understand, these annotations are used by the libraries, but is not it a bad solution overall - couldn't it be made differently? What is the logic behind that? From my prospective they make the code hard to understand, they are not processed by atom (or can I install some plugin for this?..), and it's overall strange idea. No?)

Comment: Symfony gives different configuration options. In case you don't like annotations, you can use YAML, XML, or PHP configuration as an alternative. It's up to you, really.

Comment: Not a big fan of annotations myself however I find myself in a distinct minority.  PHP 8 has support for attributes which are basically a replacement for annotations.  Most IDEs do offer support for annotations and often for Symfony specific annotations.  You can of course use other config options but the sooner you accept annotations the better off you will probably be.

Answer (score 1):

All That configuration can be stored in  php/xml/yml  files.
From my experience the idea of annotation is very convenient.
For example,  you look at  controller , and you see route (link to call controller action), data passed  ( Parameter Converter).
If it is done right,  you have all the important data in one place, just above your code.

Processing annotation by IDE it's a different story.

Check if there is any atom plugin for this , or change IDE that can handle this.
Personally, i'm using phpstrom , and i don't have any issue with annotations